# HTTP 302, 303 or 307 for tracking image url

Tags: http, http-status-code-302, http-status-code-307

I'm trying to track whether specific emails we send out are opened and therefore use a hashed url for an image on every email I send out.  Currently, when that url is requested, I log the fact that the email has been viewed (based on the hash in the url) and serve the image from the web application server (it's the same image for everybody).

At this point, we are growing to the point where it's common to get 10k plus requests in an hour and I think I can better serve our clients by giving them a 3xx HTTP response with a url for the image that is closer to them served by a dedicated CDN rather than our application server.

Which code is best?  I think either 302, 303, or 307 are the available choices.  Keep in mind that this media has no SEO value and my sole concern is delivering the static image to the client as fast as possible without causing problems with old mail clients.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [302 status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) would be your best bet if http 1.0 clients are in the potential mix. Using a 302, future requests should be made to the original URL (e.g. so you can continue to track it, compared to a 301 which would suggest future requests go to the new URL). 303 is typically used for POST requests. 307 may have some issues with [http 1.0 clients](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#Code302).

Comment: 303 would also have issues with http 1.0 clients, so I agree that the use of 302 is probably best.  Now that I think of it, in this kind of scenario we can even use a 301 since there is no need to do any future logging after the initial view of the image.

Comment: I just got nervous that email clients won't understand 3xx codes at all so I've decided to just keep serving the image directly for the near term future.

Comment: You could probably detect the email client making the request based on their user agent string, at which point you could decide whether they could handle the redirect or not.